# imadjust turns all pixels to white

Tags: matlab

I am using `imadjust` to enhance image contrast or to stretch, for example:

```
image = imread(path)
result = imadjust(image, [0.01 0.6], []);
```

but it turns all image pixels to white. How do I fix it?

Comment: How do you know that you get white pixels? What are the values of `result`? Can you post a link to an image that you're using?

Comment: Till now i'm using default image in matlab cameraman.tif

Comment: Did you normalize the values in the input image to be between 0 and 1?

Comment: I already convert the image to binary

Comment: If the image is binary, it has only 0s and 1s, hence doesn't contain any values in the range `[0.01, 0.06]`. Therefore, `imadjust` yields a constant image, which I assume that it appears as all-white. I'm not near MATLAB at the moment, but this is my suspicion.

Comment: Ok thank you for help I will try to test it in other images, and if find other thing will help please do

Comment: Try plotting a histogram of the values in your image, using `hist(image(:))` - this will show you what the distribution of values is. Then you can see whether the range you chose makes sense. For example, you could first scale image with `image = (image - min(image(:))) / (max(image(:)) - min(image(:)));` .

Comment: i tried the same code just now with cameraman.tif. It does NOT make all pixels white!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but when I used imagesc matlab function it works, for example:

```
subplot(2,1,1);
imagesc(result)
colormap(gray);
axis off
title('Result')
```

for gray scale image.
I hope this help